# [WPF]How to close popup

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, popup

I'd like to close a popup automatically with controling StaysOpen value which is popup property. I've been opening it whenever text is entered or left mouse button is clicked.
**StaysOpen** is set to **false**.

```
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="textBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"/>
        <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" OpacityMask="Transparent" StaysOpen="{Binding StaysOpen, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
               AllowsTransparency="True" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=textBox}">
            <Border CornerRadius="5" Background="#FF303030" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=textBox}">
                ...
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
```

```
private void textBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   if ((sender as TextBox).Text.Length > 0)
   {
      IsOpen = !IsOpen;
   }
}
```

When text is entered in Textbox with Popup's IsOpen is true, can be closed automatically popup when clicked out side of the control. But, in a state of textBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp function call with same situations, wouldn't be closed it automatically.(also IsOpen is true)

If i change to e.handel = true in textBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp, then can be closed automatically, through clicking the outside of it. But it have serious problem on that, can not choose any of controls in the popup. so can not use this way.

How can I safely close the popup automatically by clicking out side of control?

Comment: I'm sorry, but am I got this right?

1. When user clicks **textBox**, state of Popup will be changed if text length of clicked textBox is not zero.

2. The grid you uploaded is placed inside of larger control, and there is no problem with the current position of Popup.

Comment: @Ryu 1. yes, 2. The grid is in usercontrol. Popup apperas below textbox. Position of popup has no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not perfect, but I solved it.
I added MouseLeftButtonUpEvent instead of PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp.

```
textBox.AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonUpEvent,
                               new RoutedEventHandler(textBox_MouseLeftButtonUp),
                               true);
```

When external control is clicked, Pop up is closed automatically, and when TextBox is clicked, Pop up is opened.
However, If Pop up is displayed, When TextBox is clicked, Pop up isn't hidden.

Anyway, I think this is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TextBox`'s [`LostKeyboardFocus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.lostkeyboardfocus) event, which fires when the `TextBox` is no longer the destination for keyboard input (i.e. when the user clicks or tabs away from the control).

```
private void textBox_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    IsOpen = false;
}
```

Also, for opening the popup, I might recommend using [`GotKeyboardFocus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.gotkeyboardfocus). `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` will only work if the user sets focus by left-clicking, but the user could also use tab, etc.